# Locking my Macbook when I remove my smartcard

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, screen-lock, smart-card

I have a smartcard paired with my account on my 2015 Macbook. I'm running Catalina 10.15.4 (despite the horror stories). After I first paired the card, when I removed it my screen would lock. I changed something at some point, but I don't recall what it was. Now when I remove the card nothing happens.

Does anyone know what setting/configuration I need to modify to re-enable this?

Answer (score 2):

Figured out where to configure this. Put a check in the box next to:

System Preferences->Security & Privacy->Advanced->Turn on screen saver when login token is removed

Comment: It didn’t work for me for some reason…, I have MacOS 11.1